# How to remove first and last tag from a string in .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, tags

say I have strings as such:

```
<p>here is some text</p>
<h3>here is some header</h3>
<ul><li>fsdfsdfsd</li></ul><p>some p text</p>
```

..and in every case I just want what is between the 1st and last tag. So for example, the 3rd line would end up as

```
<li>fsdfsdfsd</li></ul><p>some p text
```

how could I do that?

Comment: The best way is using a xml parser. Don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Use HTML parser, importing it from Nuget